# Anyone know a good Javascript Prompt for the User to upgrade their browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to find a good way to notify visitors to our site to upgrade from IE6 to get full functionality. I see lots of this in use. Anyone know a good source for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put an conditional comment in for ie6. Or you could do it by checking the user agent string.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few methods specific to IE6, [you can get started here](http://www.stopie6.com/widgets.html) then style them whatever way you want...but those are the basic triggers that only IE6 will run.

I'd be amiss if I didn't recommend you read [this SO question/answer set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377133/how-to-kindly-ask-your-users-to-upgrade-from-ie6) (10k+ only) on the same topic, a lot of excellent points you need to consider.

Comment: @bradley.ayers - It was indeed deleted later, but still visible to 10k+ rep users, so leaving it in there.

Answer (score 1):

Using this answer on SO :
[**Detecting IE6 using jQuery.support**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584285/detecting-ie6-using-jquery-support/584417#584417)

You can check and if yes show your prompt

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Frame is my preferred approach to this particular problem, because if they have IE6, there's a good chance they're being forced by an IT department at their company.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started

All you need this in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

And this before end `</body>` (for jQuery):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    CFInstall.check({
         mode: "overlay",
         destination: "http://{{ host }}"
    });
  });
```

If you're not using jQuery or another library just include the call directly:

```
CFInstall.check({
   mode: "overlay",
   destination: "http://{{ host }}"
});
```

Comment: UPDATE: Chrome Frame is being [retired](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html) by Google.