# How to disable a jQuery function in IE7 only?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a jQuery function that is causing display errors in IE7. I simply want to disable the function only for IE7 instead of dealing with fixing the display errors.

Here is the code that calls the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select, input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").uniform();
});
```

So, what's the best practice to target that callout and disable it for IE7 only?

Comment: Maybe http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/. Test the browser using jQuery.support. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584285/detecting-ie6-using-jquery-support

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) allows you to view the user agent version, though it's not recommended by the jQuery team.  Instead look at [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) which is recommended for 'feature detection' to determine which browser you're using.

Using $.browser, something like (not tested):

```
if ( !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7.0) ){
...
}
```

Would do the trick

Comment: I think that logic will reject any IE, not just 7?  Try if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7.0)){...

Comment: This is great information. I think I might even need another push as to what to place within that statement to disable the function. Any ideas, I'm pretty new to this whole idea...

Comment: disregard that... figured it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's never fun, but this will work...

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fn.uniform = function() { }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Browser detection via Javascript is never reliable, but this should be since it is a valid markup comment and IE is the only browser (that I know of) sniffing for it.