# apply javascript functions to all objects in a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
$("#SidingPainting").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            }
        )
```

however I have many, like a hundred divs that I want to apply these same functions to!

Is there a way that I could make a css class and apply it to each div and then apply these functions to the css class?

Or any other ideas on how to make my life easier?

Comment: I don't get it...? a softball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery's `$` you can use CSS selectors. So just write `.className` instead of `#id`

```
$(".hoverClass").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        }
    )
```

For this you should use the `:hover` pseudo-class, but IE6 only supports it on the a-tags. So you need a JavaScript fallback like this for it.
[Detecting IE6 using jQuery.support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584285/detecting-ie6-using-jquery-support)

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need JavaScript if you simply want to change the class on hover. Just give all your `div`s a common class and use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class to change styles on hover:

```
.SidingPainting { /* this is a class, not an ID */
  ...
}

.SidingPainting:hover {
  ...
}
```