# workaround for input[type="text"]:focus in IE6

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
    border:solid 2px red;
}
```

If i was to use the above CSS rule it would not work in IE6,it just sort of disables the text control.I know the CSS bit can be taken care of using a conditional comment.Now I understand that to get the border to change in IE6 I have to use javascript or jQuery. My question is does a conditional comment similar to CSS exist for java script that binds the function that changes the border to the control only if the browser is IE6? Because modern browsers wont be needing this code.Hope I'm making some sense.

Comment: I am sorry to say that IE6 is dead!

Comment: Please do not support IE6 unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the same thing:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // IE JAVASCRIPT HERE
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ie7js, ie8js or ie9js?

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

This would in my opinion be the optimal way to solve this, as you simply include the appropriate script on your page, and it automagically fixes certain features for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Detecting IE6 using jQuery.support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584285/detecting-ie6-using-jquery-support)

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector that can do this for IE6, if you absolutely must support this feature you will have to use the help of javascript. Put this function on your page:

```
function appendInputTypeClasses() { 
 if (!document.getElementsByTagName ) 
  return; 
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
 var inputLen = inputs.length; 
 for ( i=0;i<inputLen;i++ ) { 
  if ( inputs[i].getAttribute('type') ) 
   inputs[i].className += ' '+inputs[i].getAttribute('type'); 
 } 
}
```

This will add the type of the input to the class, so you can use:

```
input[type='text'],input.text
input[type='radio'],input.radio
input[type='checkbox'],input.checkbox
```